# Magento Store - Extensions Breaking Admin

Tags: magento

Previously I was able to download extensions without a problem.  Now when I click on admin > system > magento connect > magento connect manager

I get a blank screen with a few characters:

http://skitch.com/a1anm/ntb31/http-127.0.0.1-8888-thefix-index.php-adminalan-extensions-local-index-key-9318fe8596ce8bec19757cc8ef4d8447

I am able to access the downloader via mysite.com/downloader.  The problem is evertime I download an extension now and then try to access admin > system > config I get the same blank screen error.  If I uninstall the last extension it starts working again.

I’ve tried a number of different extensions but get the same problems.  I also tried disabling all current extensions and it didn’t dix this.

Anyone know how I could fix this?  Or is it possible to reinstall the downloader without reinstalling my entire store?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a novice with Magento, but did some research on your problem that you may find helpful.

It looks like this thread over at the official Magento forums has some good suggestions:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/31791/

It may be your problem is caused by either permissions problems on your filesystem, or a corrupt core extension.

I would say that if you can't resolve your problem based on any of the advice in that thread, your best bet would be to uncomment:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

in your magento/index.php file and post here any error messages you get when trying to access Magento Connect.

Good luck!

Comment: This is good advice for anyone running into issues with Magento.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your index.php file (or some other involved file) has a byte order mark (BOM) at the top of it. Try using an encoding converter to take out the BOM.

[image: Notepad++]